# SQL aggregate totals for each previous record

Tags: sql

Is it possible to write an SQL query which aggregates all of the previous records, i.e. shows the timeline which increases with each record. This is not aggregating each record based on a logical test but aggregating using the current total.

For example for data

```
| date | new_users |
|------|-----------|
| day0 | 2         |
| day1 | 1         |
| day2 | 3         |
```

I would like to get

```
| date | total_users|
|------|------------|
| day0 | 2          |
| day1 | 3          |
| day2 | 6          |
```

Comment: Pretty much the definition of "windows functions". You always need to define a clear unequivocal ordering, ideally with no ties in ordering (i.e. the ordering columns act as a "key"). Otherwise it doesn't make too much sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want a cumulative sum:

```
select date,
       sum(new_users) over (order by date) as total_users
from t;
```